# Dynamic graphics are less responsive inside a Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, graphs-and-networks, dynamic

I have some code which displays a `GraphPlot` and allows the user to click on any vertex in the graph to display some information about that vertex in a popup window. There is two-way highlighting between the popup and the vertex, so that if the user hovers over either the vertex or the popup window, both the vertex and the popup will be highlighted (the vertex by changing size and the popup by changing colour).

I do this by defining a `VertexRenderingFunction` for the graph plot which uses `Module` to create a unique symbol for each vertex. This symbol is set to `True` whenever the mouse is over the vertex or the popup window, and the dynamic highlighting is determined by the value of the symbol.

This works okay (though I'd be interested in better ways to accomplish the same effect). However, as soon as I put the `GraphPlot` inside a `Manipulate`, the highlighting becomes rather sluggish, even if the `Manipulate` is not changing the plot in any way. I don't understand why that happens.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
(* create some data *)
data = Thread[RandomChoice[Range[200], 350] -> RandomChoice[Range[200], 350]];

(* define the vertex rendering function *)
vrf := Module[{mo},
   PopupWindow[
    Dynamic[
     mo = CurrentValue["MouseOver"];
     {PointSize[Dynamic[If[mo, 0.03, 0.01]]], Point[#1]}],
    Dynamic[
     mo = CurrentValue["MouseOver"];
     Panel["Popup Window Text", Background -> Dynamic[If[mo, Pink, White]]]]
    ]] &;

(* graph plot *)
gp = GraphPlot[data, VertexRenderingFunction -> vrf]
```

This works nicely. But if I do this:

```
Manipulate[gp, {x, 0, 10}, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]
```

it is much less responsive. Can anyone tell me why this happens, and more importantly how to prevent it?

I'm using version 8.0.4 by the way.

**NB**  The first argument of the `Manipulate` in my example is deliberately independent of `x`. The slider control is nothing to do with the problem, it is just there to make a valid Manipulate expression. I have used `TrackedSymbols :> {x}` to make doubly certain that Manipulate isn't tracking any symbols inside the GraphPlot. In my real application the `Manipulate` does useful things, but I realised as I stripped the code down that merely being inside a `Manipulate` affects the responsiveness of the plot, even if the `Manipulate` doesn't change the plot in any way.

Comment: I can't reproduce the "horribly" part here yet

Comment: Possibly related to this (very annoying) bug: http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#Pitfalls  (And I can reproduce on 8.0.4 linux)

Comment: I get a detectable slow-down on 9.0.0, on an oldish, 2-core, 2.5GHz Mac. CPU usage in the Manipulate is almost 50%  (one full core); the non-Manipulate uses about 10% less.  It's worse on 8.0.4.  Looks like with Manipulate, it's hitting the wall.

Comment: @Nasser, that's the point - the dynamic interactivity in my `GraphPlot` is affected by being inside a `Manipulate`, even when there is nothing in the `GraphPlot` affected by `x`. In my real application the `Manipulate` does useful things of course.

Comment: @Nasser, no I'm not moving the slider at all. The problem is with the highlighting of the dots as the mouse moves over them. I only put the control variable in there to make it a valid `Manipulate` expression. The `TrackedSymbols` was just to make doubly certain that `Manipulate` wasn't tracking any symbols inside the `GraphPlot`. I will edit the question to make this clearer.

Comment: With 8.0.4 I see substantial slowdown wrapping in `Manipulate` but barely any slowdown when wrapping in `DynamicModule`. I have a bias against `Manipulate` but in this case if you want to add other controls seems like DM is the way to go. (also tried `Tooltip` instead of popup windows and worked fine in DM). I've been attempting some larger scale dynamic data interfaces lately in order to mimic Tableau and finding that Mma probably hasn't been designed for interfaces with large numbers of tooltips, etc.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, I'm getting some slowdown with `DynamicModule` but not as much as `Manipulate`. In my actual application there are tooltips *and* popups, and the popups contain a lot more content, including buttons. As you can probably imagine, the performance with `Manipulate` becomes quite appalling! I was hoping to stick with `Manipulate` as I will be deploying to CDF and the `SaveDefinitions` option is convenient, but perhaps I need to make the jump to `DynamicModule`. Thanks for your input.

Comment: If i change `Module` to `DynamicModule` and `SetDelayed` to `Set` in the definition of `vrf`, i get better responsiveness (ver 8.0.4 on Windows Vista).

Comment: Agree with @kguler. Should have picked that up. If you intend to use this in a web interface I don't think you can use popups (maybe someone can clarify). I use insets instead to keep it all in the graphics.

Comment: @kguler, I can't use `DynamicModule` as that stops the highlighting working properly (the graph vertex fails to highlight when you put the mouse over the popup window). But it's interesting that `Set` makes such a difference. I'll have to play with it a bit more tomorrow, it's late here and I'm tired... Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is because you need to define two mouse over variables -- mouse over your point and mouse over your popup text. If you do that then it works as required in `DynamicModule` (though still very slow in `Manipulate`).

Comment: `vrf = DynamicModule[{mo1 = False, mo2 = False},
   PopupWindow[
    Dynamic[
     mo1 = CurrentValue["MouseOver"];
     {PointSize[Dynamic@If[mo1 || mo2, 0.03, 0.01]], Point[#1]}],
    Dynamic[
     mo2 = CurrentValue["MouseOver"];
     Panel["Popup Window Text", 
      Background -> Dynamic@If[mo2, Pink, White]]]]] &`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, @kguler, Set and SetDelayed shouldn't make a difference given that it is a `Function` that holds anyway, but who knows

Comment: @SimonWoods, it seems all `Dynamics` inside `PointSize` are updated together. Seems buggy and it makes things slower. Try `Dynamic[PointSize@If[mo, 0.03, 0.01]]` instead

Comment: @Rojo that was kgulers suggestion. I did not notice any difference. As per my comment I don't notice issues when using `DynamicModule`.

Comment: @rojo with `Dynamic[Point[...]]` and my defn of `vrf` above `Manipulate` now responds quite well for me.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch then Simon will be happy tomorrow :)

Comment: It remains unclear why different code is needed in `Manipulate` compared to `DynamicModule` to achieve comparable performance. `Manipulate` is a strange beast IMO.

Comment: @Rojo, you've nailed it - moving the `Dynamic` outside the `PointSize` makes all the difference. I have no idea why, I find this dynamic stuff very confusing.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, your definition of `vrf` together with Rojo's idea looks like the right way to do it. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Glad we helped. However, neither of us seem to be able to actually answer the question.

Comment: @Rojo maybe join them in a community wiki post?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch sure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting the `Dynamic` wrapper of the point graphics outside the list seems to make a difference.

```
data = Thread[RandomChoice[Range[200], 350] -> RandomChoice[Range[200], 350]];

vrf = Module[{mo}, 
    PopupWindow[Dynamic[mo = CurrentValue["MouseOver"];
      Dynamic@{PointSize[If[mo, 0.03, 0.01]], Point[#1]}, 
      TrackedSymbols -> {}], Dynamic[mo = CurrentValue["MouseOver"];
      Panel["Popup Window Text", Background -> Dynamic[If[mo, Pink, White]]]]]] &;
```

I notice an improvement in both

```
gp = GraphPlot[data, VertexRenderingFunction -> vrf]
```

and especially in

```
Manipulate[gp, {x, 0, 10}]
```

The `Manipulate` is nearly as fast as the plain dynamic graphics.

---

I noticed that

```
Manipulate[gp]
```

does not behave as badly as the `Manipulate` with a slider, although perhaps slightly worse than just `gp`.

A wild guess is that `Manipulate` inserts an `EventHandler` in front of the output that causes extra checking.  For instance, it might be that a `"MouseOver"` event is checked at all points instead of only the relevant one.  I tried `CurrentValue[foo++; "MouseOver"]`, which showed that it is updated only at one point, but that doesn't mean the front end doesn't do extra checking behind the scenes.  [Update: This seems less likely after further investigation.  See below.]

The wild guess does not really explain why the solution above works, though.  It seems like familiarity with the internals workings of `Manipulate` will be needed to explain what the problem is.

---

**Updated Edit**: A better guess.

It seems that wrapping the visible object with `Dynamic` is to be preferred to wrapping `Dynamic` around code inside the object.  For instance, as in the above or better yet as in @Rojo's comment,

```
Dynamic[PointSize[If...]]
```

is better than

```
PointSize[Dynamic[If...]]
```

**Why might that be?**

I stress *might*, because I don't know.
The system is designed to dynamically update objects that appear in a visible cell in a notebook. Dependencies have to be parsed, and at a superficial glance, it seems to me it might be easier if the visible object is the dynamic object and not some internal part of it that in itself is not visible.  For instance it would be better if `Dynamic` wrapped the `PointSize` directive and not the `If` statement inside `PointSize`.  In any case, **all the points are being updated** when `Dynamic` is inside `PointSize`, as observed by @Rojo.  Further there are **four updates per mouse-over for each point** (estimated), which is quite a lot.

Now the order of `PointSize@Dynamic@...` seems confusing.  It seems to say `PointSize`, being outside, is not dynamic, only what is inside it.  So what does the system do when the inside changes?  The original code has

```
Dynamic[mo = CurrentValue["MouseOver"];
 {PointSize[Dynamic[If[mo, 0.03, 0.01]]], Point[#1]}]
```

Notice that `PointSize` is itself inside another `Dynamic`.  One ought to be able to remove the inside `Dynamic`.

**An improvement**

When the inside `Dynamic`s are removed, you run into another problem already pointed out implicitly by @MikeHoneychurch that each of the two linked objects, the point and the popup, overwrites `mo`.  So you need separate state variables.  This led to the following:

```
vrf = Module[{mo1 = False, mo2 = False}, 
    PopupWindow[Dynamic[mo1 = CurrentValue["MouseOver"];
      {PointSize[If[mo1 || mo2, 0.03, 0.01]], Point[#1]}], 
     Dynamic[mo2 = CurrentValue["MouseOver"];
      Panel["Popup Window Text", Background -> If[mo1 || mo2, Pink, White]]]]] &;
```

But further investigation reveals that there is still some inefficiency.  There are **two updates per mouse-over** on a `Point`.  A change `CurrentValue["MouseOver"]` causes an update to `mo1`; since `PointSize` depends on `mo1`, another update is incurred.  This led me to the following changes.

**A better improvement**

Here is a more efficient implementation:

```
vrf = Module[{mo1 = False, mo2 = False},
    PopupWindow[
      Dynamic@{PointSize[If[(mo1 = CurrentValue["MouseOver"]) || mo2, 0.03, 0.01]], Point[#1]},
      Panel["Popup Window Text",
        Background -> Dynamic@If[mo1 || (mo2 = CurrentValue["MouseOver"]), Pink, White]]]] &;
```

It has **one update per mouse-over**.  Putting the assignment inside `If` makes the expression for the point not depend on the value of `mo1`.  Ditto for the expression for the `Panel`.

**Why does `Manipulate` run so slowly? Hmm…**

I'm beginning to agree with @MikeHoneychurch that `Manipulate` is a strange beast.  I attempted to measure the CPU load by running my mouse quickly back and forth over closely connected points.  My computer is a 2.5GHz 2-core Mac, and the monitor reports loads as percentages that can add up to 200% (100% per core).  It's not an exact measurement, obviously, but it seems to reveal something about the behavior.

Using the original code, without `Manipulate`, the load is 80%-90%, about %50+ by the front end and 30%+ by the kernel, and the response time is ok but noticeably slower than any of the improvements.
With `Manipulate` the load is about 100%+ when the graph is inside `Manipulate`, 40%+ by the front end, 60% by the kernel.  Compared to the performance without `Manipulate` cited above, the decrease in the front end load is reflected in the slow performance.  The substantial increase in the kernel load, about double, reflects a substantial amount of additional computation.  However, the number of updates isn't different than the original dynamic graphics, four for each point (all points updated every mouse-over).  By comparison, with any of the improvements I can get the front end up above 60% and the kernel remains below 2%, whether or not inside `Manipulate`, and the response is quite rapid.

I have not been able to think of a reason for the increased demand on the kernel inside.

Comment: or you could just use Mouseover: vrf2 := PopupWindow[
    Mouseover[{PointSize[0.01], Point[#1]}, {PointSize[0.03], 
      Point[#1]}], 
    Mouseover[Panel["Popup Window Text", Background -> White], 
     Panel["Popup Window Text", Background -> Pink]]] &; or without DynamicModuel:  vrf1 := PopupWindow[
    Dynamic[{PointSize[If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], 0.03, 0.01]], 
      Point[#1]}
     ], Dynamic[
     Panel["Popup Window Text", 
      Background -> If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Pink, White]]
     ]] &;

Comment: Thanks Michael, moving the `Dynamic` outside `PointSize` was Rojo's suggestion too, and it seems to be the key to getting decent performance.

Comment: @halmir, I need the highlighting to happen on both the vertex *and* the popup when the mouse is over *either* of them. Hence the need for a symbol to hold the current mouseover state.

Comment: Should this be a community wiki too? Or part of the other one?  I'm afraid I don't completely understand the etiquette or purpose of them.

Comment: @MichaelE2, in this case I think Mike made the answer a community wiki simply because it was a combined effort to find a solution. I think your answer adds some interesting ideas about the cause of the problem, so I would leave it as it is.

Comment: Thanks for your extra work on this, Michael, very useful.

Comment: Nice summary, +1!

Answer (score 5):

As per comment thread the thing that produces a more responsive `Manipulate` is to use `Dynamic[Point[If[...]]]` rather than `Point[Dynamic[If[...]]]`. Using two mouse over variables enables you to mouse over the popup and change the size of the point.

```
(*create some data*)
data = Thread[
   RandomChoice[Range[200], 350] -> RandomChoice[Range[200], 350]];

(*define the vertex rendering function*)

vrf = DynamicModule[{mo1 = False, mo2 = False}, 
    PopupWindow[
     Dynamic[mo1 = 
       CurrentValue["MouseOver"]; {Dynamic@
        PointSize[If[mo1 || mo2, 0.03, 0.01]], Point[#1]}], 
     Dynamic[mo2 = CurrentValue["MouseOver"]; 
      Panel["Popup Window Text", 
       Background -> Dynamic@If[mo2, Pink, White]]]]] &;

(*graph plot*)gp = GraphPlot[data, VertexRenderingFunction -> vrf]
```

and the `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[gp, {x, 0, 10}, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]
```