# Synchronizing the camera view of multiple Image3D panels within a Manipulate interface

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, image3d

I'm trying to synchronize the camera view of multiple `Image3D` panels displayed within a `Manipulate` interface.

A random 3D image will do for demonstration purposes.

```
theimg = Image3D[RandomReal[1, {20, 30, 40}], ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image: random 3D image]

Here is the code I have which attempts to synchronize the camera views of two Image3D panels. The code is based upon the StackExchange answers [Extract current viewing parameters from a 3D view](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5375/extract-current-viewing-parameters-from-a-3d-view) and [Synchronizing manual rotations for multiple Graphics3D outputs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21516/synchronizing-manual-rotations-for-multiple-graphics3d-outputs).

```
Options[imgcompare] = {SphericalRegion -> True};
imgcompare[img1_, img2_, opts : OptionsPattern[{imgcompare, Image3D}]] := 
DynamicModule[{vv = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}, vp = {1.3, -2.4, 2.0}},
    Grid[
        {{Image3D[img1, opts, Sequence @@ Options[imgcompare], 
                ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]],
            Image3D[img2, opts, Sequence @@ Options[imgcompare], 
                ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]]}}]]
```

The code works fine outside of a `Manipulate` statement as demonstrated by the code below. You can manually rotate one of the 3D images and the other one rotates in synch.

```
imgcompare[theimg, Binarize[Erosion[theimg, 1]]]
```

[image: image synch works outside of a Manipulate statement]

However, synchronization doesn't work if you try to call the function within a `Manipulate` statement.

```
Manipulate[imgcompare[theimg, Binarize[Erosion[theimg, n]]], 
 {{n, 1, "Erosion"}, 1, 4, 1, SetterBar}]
```

[image: initial error]

Initially, the `Manipulate` window gives an error. In the message window, the errors given are:

> Viewpoint \$CellContext`vp$13957 is not a triple of numbers or a recognized symbolic form.

and

> The ViewVertical vector is too short to establish the up direction.

If you inspect the value of the variable `vp$13957` (the number part of the variable name changes for each execution of the code), you can see it is undefined (the output just repeats the symbol name). I'm baffled as to how this variable could be undefined as I explicitly initialize `vp` and `vv` in the `DynamicModule`.

Despite the error, if I ignore the error and try to manually rotate one of the images, it seems to work at first and the panels are synchronized.
[image: synchronization seems to work anyway, at first]

However, if I click the `SetterBar` to change the value, the error returns.
[image: error returns]

If I again ignore the error and manually rotate one of the panels, the error goes away again, but synchronization is broken. The two panels rotate independently.
[image: synchronization broken]

Why does the camera view synchronization fail when the `imgcompare` function is called within a `Manipulate` expression?

Comment: Minimal example of your problem can be observed with: `Dynamic@DynamicModule[{vp = {2.0, 2.0, 1.}}, 
  Image3D[RandomReal[1, {2, 2, 2}], ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]]]`.

Comment: And since this works: `Dynamic@DynamicModule[{vp = {2.0, 2.0, 1.}}, 
  Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]]]` I don't know what to say...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have not fully diagnosed the problem, but it appears as if `vv` and `vp` are not initialized when you effectively wrap a Dyanmic module within a dynamic module (which is what you've done with the Manipulate.

Changing your DynamicModule into the Manipulate seems to get the result you desire if you Initialize `vv` and `vp`:

```
Clear[vv, vp]
Manipulate[
 With[{img1 = theimg, img2 = Binarize[Erosion[theimg, n]]}, 
  Grid[{{Image3D[img1, Sequence @@ Options[imgcompare], 
      ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]], 
     Image3D[img2, Sequence @@ Options[imgcompare], 
      ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]]}}]], {{n,
    1, "Erosion"}, 1, 4, 1, SetterBar}, 
 Initialization -> (vv = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}; vp = {1.3, -2.4, 2.0};)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's another workaround: Use `Show` to wrap the `Image3D` with `Graphics3D`.  This changes how the graphics are processed by the Front End (I suspect).  Evidently the FE is grabbing the graphics parameters such as the view point, and dealing with it.  I don't know enough to give a complete explanation.  Certain things are optimized, such as using the GPU efficiently, and the FE always has had to control the `View*` properties.

There are two things that complicate things: how `Image3D` graphics are handled, and the nested `DynamicModules` (`Manipulate` creates a `DynamicModule` to hold the variables and code).  Kuba's comments shows something different happening with `Image3D` and `Graphics3D`; bobthechemist's answer shows that having everything in one module works, too.  The workaround I'm proposing takes advantage of Kuba's observation.

The changes to `imgcompare` are to use `Show` and to add the view options to the `Show`.  This puts them with the `Graphics3D`, and for whatever reason, the Front End plays nicely with them. (It's not clear to me how the OP would want to handle the options here, so I just left the code alone.  Users should adapt it to their own requirements)

```
Options[imgcompare] = {SphericalRegion -> True};
imgcompare[img1_, img2_, opts : OptionsPattern[{imgcompare, Image3D}]] := 
 DynamicModule[{vv = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}, vp = {1.3, -2.4, 2.0}}, 
  Grid[{{
     Show[Image3D[img1, opts, Sequence @@ Options[imgcompare]], 
      ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv], 
      Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True], 
     Show[Image3D[img2, opts, Sequence @@ Options[imgcompare]], 
      ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv], 
      Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True]}}]]
```

**Notes on the difficulties**

Some observations. It might be a bug with how `Image3D` is handled.

1. In dynamic settings such as `ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]`, the viewpoint is set to the code `Dynamic[vp]`, which is in itself not a list of numbers or a symbol like `Front`.  The dynamic updating system (FE/Kernel) is supposed to replace this with the value of `vp` when the graphics are typeset/displayed.  Is the value of `vp` is not being substituted? Or is the variable is uninitialized?  Sticking a `Print` in shows that it seems to be initialized.
2. Adding a row `{ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]},` to the `Grid` in the OP's `imgcompare` shows that `vp` in the image(s) and in the row are not updated together.  The row is never updated.  However they are updated together with the `Show` workaround above.
3. Changing `n` causes a new `DynamicModule` to be instantiated (by a call to `imgcompare`).  This should reset the view points.  It does in the above workaround, but...
4. In the OP's version: Rotating just one of the images seems to cause the FE to take control of the view point for that image and keep control of it.  If `n` is changed, the other's view point is reset, but the view point of the rotated one stays the same.  The view points are now unlinked and unsynchronized.  Presumably, they are now `vp`s from different `DynamicModule`s.  If both images are rotated before changing `n`, then the view points will remain synchronized whenever `n` is changed.

I cannot see a way to blame this behavior on an error in the OP's code.  It is probably worth reporting the problem to Wolfram support to see what they say.  If it is a bug, they will appreciate hearing about it.  (And if they point out an error, maybe Matt could answer his own question.)

Comment: And then there's the [Manipulate-is-a-strange-beast theory](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19743/dynamic-graphics-are-less-responsive-inside-a-manipulate#comment60651_19743)