# Variable scoping confusion

Tags: manipulate, scoping

Forgive me if this question has been asked prior (I wouldn't even know where to start looking for an answer to this problem to be honest).  I know the following code in Mathematica works:

```
temp = {x^2,Sin[x]}; (* Just a random list with functions inside *)
f = Function[x,Evaluate[temp[[1]]]];
f[3]
```

The code would output the appropriate 9 as required.  However, the problem occurs when I try to use a similar logic within a Manipulate function as shown below:

```
Manipulate[
  Module[{temp,f},
    temp = {x^2,Sin[x]};
    f = Function[x,Evaluate[temp[[1]]]];
    {num, f[num]}],
    {num, 3}]
```

Running the above code yields an output `{3, x^2}` and it doesn't change for any `num`. Any suggestions would be exceedingly helpful.  For context as to why I'm doing this, I'm solving a differential equation within the `Manipulate` expression (where end conditions are manipulated by the controls). Using `DSolve` outputs the required functions in a list and I would simply like to graph them and their derivatives.  If you know a better method of doing that, that would also be helpful.

#### Update

It appears that the problem is, in fact, with variable typing as shown below:

```
temp = {x^2, Sin[x]}; (*Just a random list with functions inside*)
f = Function[x, Evaluate[temp[[1]]]];
f[3]
Manipulate[
  Module[{temp, f}, 
    temp = {x^2, Sin[x]};
    f = Function[x, Evaluate[temp[[1]]]];
    {Head[temp], Head[f], Head[f[num]], Head[f[3]]}], 
  {num, 5}]
{Head[temp], Head[f], Head[f[3]]}
```

Note that the `Head[f[num]]` and `Head[f[3]]` within the `Manipulate` expression evaluate to `Power` whereas the `Head[f[3]]` outside evaluates to `Integer` (as expected). Using `IntegerPart[]` however still doesn't yield an appropriate answer. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I misdiagnosed the problem originally, somehow assuming `Manipulate` was the culprit, when in fact it is `Module`, as @Kuba pointed out (thanks!).  This is discussed in this Q&A:

[Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia)

I would add that renaming the argument `x` to `x$` in `Function[x, Evaluate[body]]` occurs whenever the `body` contains `Module` variables other than the `Function` argument(s).

```
Module[{temp, f},
 temp = {x^2, Sin[x]};
 f = Function[x, Evaluate[temp[[1]]]];
 f]
(*  Function[x$, x^2]  *)
```

However, no renaming occurs in the following, even though `x` is a `Module` variable: the argument stays `x` and perhaps unexpectedly, the instances of `x` in the body are not renamed to the `Module` variable `x$746197`, even though the expression is evaluated first. (This is discussed in "[I define a variable as local to a module BUT then the module uses its global value! Why?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72758/i-define-a-variable-as-local-to-a-module-but-then-the-module-uses-its-global-val/)")

```
Module[{temp, f, x},
 f = Function[x, Evaluate[{x^2, Sin[x]}[[1]]]];
 {x, f}]
(*  {x$746197, Function[x, x^2]}  *)
```

*Original answer:*

Under certain conditions, localized variables are changed when code is inserted into the localized body:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{temp, f},
  temp = {x^2, Sin[x]};
  f = Function[x, Evaluate[temp[[1]]]];
  {num, f[num], f}],
 {num, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the function argument has been changed to `x$`, which does not match the `x` in the body.  I'm not sure why; "`Manipulate` is a strange beast" [has been said before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19743/dynamic-graphics-are-less-responsive-inside-a-manipulate#comment60651_19743).

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{temp, f},
  temp = {x^2, Sin[x]};
  f = Function @@ {x, temp[[1]]};
  {num, f[num], f}],
 {num, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Related:

- [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia) (added in update)
- [I define a variable as local to a module BUT then the module uses its global value! Why?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72758/i-define-a-variable-as-local-to-a-module-but-then-the-module-uses-its-global-val/)
- [Conflict with variables in pure functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78858/conflict-with-variables-in-pure-functions/)

Comment: Thank you very much; out of curiosity, could you explain what the Function @@ {....} did, as opposed to the normal function call, to make it work as expected?

Comment: @Tired_College_Student The list `{x, ...}` (= List[x, temp[[1]]}`) is evaluated before the head `List` is replaced by `Function`.  So the body is not changed *after* `Function` is in place, but before. If the body is changed after, the parameter `x` is renamed `x$`. `Manipulate` reprocesses its code, rewriting its variables, such as `num`, by adding `$$` to them (e.g. `num$$`) and so forth -- it's somewhat complicated, too much so for a comment.  I think somehow this causes the `x` to become `x$` when inside the `Manipulate`.

Comment: "I'm not sure why" - unless I missed your point, because of the standard renaming: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478

Comment: @Kuba I guess I was tired. I didn't check `Module` and assumed it was `Manipulate`.  The Q&A you linked mainly discusses `Module[{x,..}, Function[x, Evaluate[..]]]`, or so it seems to me; but the renaming of `x` occurs whenever the `Evaluate[..]` contains any `Module` variables, whether there is a naming conflict or not. Nonetheless, this seems to be dupe.